# How to create generic UITableviewCell which have a way to pass the generic datatype to the main UIViewController via delegates or some other way?

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview, generics, delegates

I am trying to create a generic UITableViewcell which can infer the generic type to concrete type while creating cell like the following:

```
    protocol ConfigureCell {
        associatedtype DataType
        func configure(data:DataType)
    }

            class AbstractCell<T:Codable>: UITableViewCell , ConfigureCell  {

            func configure(data: T) {

            }

            var delegate : AbstractCellDelegate!
        }


class UserCell:AbstractCell<UserDetail> {

    override func configure(data: UserDetail) {

    }
}

    protocol AbstractCellDelegate {
     associatedtype DataType
    func cellBtnClicked(model:DataType,index:Int,cell:AbstractCell<DataType>)
    func cellBtnClicked(model:DataType,index:Int,cell:AbstractCell<DataType>,action:String)
    func cellBtnClicked(model:DataType?,index:Int,cell:AbstractCell<DataType>,action:String)
}
```

[image]

[image]

I also have some delegates that can be used to pass related data to the main UIViewController if needed . The delegates are working fine if the cell is not generic but after creating a generic cell i cannot use delegate methods with the following error. This may be solved with Type erasure but that will be overkill for this as i do not understand them much. Is there a way that i can create a generic cell and also have a way to call method to the main UIViewcontroller class via delegates or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Credits [Swift Associated Type Design Patterns](https://medium.com/dunnhumby-data-science-engineering/swift-associated-type-design-patterns-6c56c5b0a73a)

```
protocol ConfigureCell {
    associatedtype DataType
    func configure(data: DataType)
}

class AbstractCell<T: Codable>: UITableViewCell, ConfigureCell {
    func configure(data: T) {
    }

    var delegate: AbstractCellDelegate?
}

class UserCell: AbstractCell<UserDetail> {
    override func configure(data: UserDetail) {
    }
}

protocol AbstractCellDelegate {
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable, index: Int, cell: Any)
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable, index: Int, cell: Any, action: String)
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable?, index: Int, cell: Any, action: String)
}

extension AbstractCellDelegate {
    // dont need them
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable, index: Int, cell: Any) {}
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable, index: Int, cell: Any, action: String) {}
    func cellBtnClicked(model: Codable?, index: Int, cell: Any, action: String) {}
}

protocol CellDelegate: AbstractCellDelegate {
    associatedtype DataType: Codable
    func cellBtnClicked(model: DataType, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<DataType>)
    func cellBtnClicked(model: DataType, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<DataType>, action: String)
    func cellBtnClicked(model: DataType?, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<DataType>, action: String)
}

struct UserDetail: Codable {
}

struct MyDataType: Codable {
}

class MyViewController: CellDelegate {
    func cellBtnClicked(model: MyDataType, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<MyDataType>) {
    }

    func cellBtnClicked(model: MyDataType, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<MyDataType>, action: String) {
    }

    func cellBtnClicked(model: MyDataType?, index: Int, cell: AbstractCell<MyDataType>, action: String) {
    }

    typealias DataType = MyDataType
}
```

**EDIT**
You can try this

```
protocol ConfigureCell {
    associatedtype DataType
    func configure(model: DataType)
}

protocol DelegateCell {
    associatedtype DataType
    func btnTap(model: DataType)
}

class UserCell: ConfigureCell, DelegateCell {
    typealias DataType = UserDetail

    var btnTapHandler: ((DataType) -> Void)?

    func btnTap(model: DataType) {
        btnTapHandler?(model)
    }

    var model: DataType?
    func configure(model: DataType) {
        self.model = model
    }

    @IBAction func tap() {
        if let model = model {
            btnTap(model: model)
        }
    }
}

struct UserDetail {
    var name = "Manas"
}

class TableViewController {

    var items = [UserDetail]()

    func cellForIndexPath(row: Int) {
        let cell = UserCell()
        cell.configure(model: items[row])
        cell.btnTapHandler = { data in
            print(data.name)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello chandOnly23 , thanks for your suggestion but the issue is still the same. To use celldelegate i will need to declare it in some class from where the methods will be called but whenever i try to declare celldelegate, it shows me error : "Protocol 'CellDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"